# Move files based on list of old and new file paths

Tags: macos, file-management, file-transfer, mv

What is an efficient way to rename files in OSX/BSD from a text file for files assumed to stay in original folder, but in the format of;

> `/path/old file name.ext`**\t**`new file name.ext`

There may be say thousands of entries using TAB delimiter between entries.and any line delimiter used in Windows,OSX or Linux.

File names may contain any valid character including _'!?~*&^%$#@,.∑´®†¥¨ˆ¬˚∆˙©ƒ & Asian font characters

Names end with a dotted extension e.g. `.xxx`.

Comment: How are "old file name" and "new file name" separated? Are those file names allowed to contain spaces?

Comment: I think a reverse parse of the string might extract the end of the folder path from the last entry of "/" to a variable so it can be used in a valid syntax for BSD using  mv %path/%oldname %path/%newname , so that may require some smart script parsing. I am BSD challenged at the  moment.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is there a space separating the entries? If yes, can we assume the entries themselves contain no spaces at all? If not, is there a `\t` between the entries, or something else to split the entries at?

Comment: File names are separated with at least 1 space, but then so are words within a file name, so the only distinction is that names end with a dotted extension e.g. .xxx

Comment: That's a really bad format to work with.. oh well. Is it at least one space or one space exactly? Are the extensions of the same size (i.e. three characters)? Do all files have an extension? (Sorry that I ask so much, but you gave us not a lot to work with …)

Comment: This is a horrible file format, as it'll break as soon as there are file names with dots somewhere in the middle. I'd try to get a better file format.

Comment: Yes, its not my format and it is terrible, yes at least one space delimiter and all .xxx 3 letter extensions.. will test now..

Comment: can't find string "EOS" anywhere before EOF
after running both ruby scripts.. I guess my assumption is I am missing a small detail....    script contains.. paths = <<-EOS etc.. I feel silly asking, what does this /path/old... do here? or do I need to understand shovel more?

Comment: found a space after EOS from copy&paste of code... trashed the shovel....  now says ... /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:505:in `rename': No such file or directory - /path/old file name.ext or /path/new file name.ext (Errno::ENOENT)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:505:in `mv'
etc ... I think I need to replace that with something for input.txt

Comment: @TonyStewart I edited my answer to remove the space. Just copy and paste the contents of text file inside the HEREDOC.

Comment: drop box https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tdufcnh7v9kelur/9X_sTpOhN0/Ruby

Comment: I recall hating how OSX replaces a folder contents with  drag and drop unlike Windows Merge for folders with same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated version:

This one takes as specification:

- Each statement on one line
- Records are separated by a `\t` character.

That makes it much easier:

```
require 'fileutils'
File.open("input.txt", 'r').each_line do |l|
  next if l.strip.empty?
  f = l.split("\t")
  dir = File.dirname f[0]
  if File.exists? f[0]
    p "Moving #{f[0]} to #{dir}/#{f[1].strip}"
    # FileUtils.mv f[0], "#{dir}/#{f[1].strip}"
  else
    p "#{f[0]} does not exist."
  end
end
```

Save this as a file and call it with `ruby filename.rb`. It'll read from `input.txt` in the same directory and just move the files.

Uncomment the `# FileUtils…` line for it to actually move something. This should tell you if the original file can't be found.

---

Your original input specification was:

- Each statement on one line
- Records are *not* terminated or separated except for their extension
- Records can contain spaces, and delimiter can be multiple spaces ("at least 1 space")

One therefore has to fall back to matching the first file extension, then interpreting this as the first argument. Then, we need to remove this part from the original line, remove beginning and trailing whitespace, and construct the `mv` command.

Additional assumptions:

- All extensions have only three characters, not more, not less
- The file names themselves don't contain a dot (otherwise this breaks)

Since you're on OS X, let's just use Ruby:

```
require 'fileutils'
File.open("input.txt", 'r').each_line do |l|
  next if l.strip.empty?
  old_file = l[0, l.index(/\.[a-z0-9]{3}/i) + 4]
  dir = File.dirname old_file
  new_filename = l.sub(old_file, '').lstrip.chomp
  p "Moving #{old_file} to #{dir}/#{new_filename}"
  # FileUtils.mv old_file, "#{dir}/#{new_filename}"
end
```

Comment: tony.rb:2: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from tony.rb:1:in `each_line'
 from tony.rb:1

Comment: @TonyStewart Some line in the input probably didn't contain `\.[a-z]{3}`. Try running it on a subset of lines in the input or removing empty lines.

Comment: This challenge becomes even more difficult when you consider the depth of filename specs and incompatibilities across platforms but I choose to **ignore that* for now..  e.g Chinese font text and RTL Language fonts

Comment: nope>> ruby tony.rb
tony.rb:2: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from tony.rb:1:in `each_line'
<< I agree it is insane. I could do it in excel using string match for file extensions using a common set of a few .xxx and last occurrence of / to denote beginning of file name.back in 3 hrs

Comment: it just responded with error presumably from file name content outside A~z. I posted both ruby and input.txt in dropbox 7hrs ago

Comment: see dropbox example files?  still no go.. same error

Comment: @TonyStewart Yeah, of course it won't work if there are numbers in the extension. You have to add `0-9` there, see my updated answer. Next time, please be way more specific with your requirements, else it's hard to diagnose or even answer to begin with. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @slhck for helping me understand the syntax of Ruby with my example question. I thought my generalization of .xxx  extension would suffice but I should know better to state all the assumptions such as filespec rules and language and UTF-8. Some filenames deleted had Japanese characters. will try now.

Comment: @TonyStewart No problem, let me know if you need anything. By the way: There exist *plenty* of tools for renaming MP3s based on the path they're in or their ID3 tag information. So you could have probably just asked about that and would have received a better solution ;)

Comment: @slhck perhaps but thats too easy.  An old dog trying to learn scripting since HPbasic and Forth days is good for my soul.  Error log put in dropbox. Take a peek. How do I append other characters in file name filter syntax _&' etc

Comment: @TonyStewart Okay, the culprit was single quotes `'` in the file names. Please update the Ruby script with the code I posted and try again — you need to uncomment the `# FileUtils.mv` line of course. // The extension search is just a basic regular expression – you can tweak it as you like.

Comment: still many errors ...hmm..I paraphrase...  <old_file> exists but error says {No such file...} to  {old_file} OR {new_filename} before new is created??? in line ending with (Errno::ENOENT) .. see dropbox "Ruby error take 2.txt" some errors show {new_filename} to {new_filename}

Comment: @TonyStewart It looks for "03 - Goodbye, Farewell.mp3" but in fact the folder only has "Goodbye, Farewell.mp3". No wonder it doesn't work!

Comment: Of course duh... disabled iTunes bad organizer.. creating new input1.txt

Comment: @TonyStewart Okay, I again updated the script, which now uses tab-based separators. That makes it so much easier to parse. Please check it out and report back if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, muchos gracious, now I know filenames are UTF-16, RegEx is a little more understandable and Ruby isn't so scary if you get great advice from experts. Now where is that ice cream for my humble pie